# PostgreSQL file import to table eror

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanted to transfer the file I created for testing to the postgresql file, and I did this with the command:`psql -h localhost -d test -U postgres -f C:\test1.sql` it gave me an error like this:

```
`ERROR: Syntax error in place " ' "
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `test1` (`idcustomer`, `testid`, `customername`, `custlastname`, `birthid...`
```

MY CODE:

```
`-- phpMyAdmin SQL 
-- version 5.2.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 22, 2022 at 04:31 PM
-- Server version: 10.4.25-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 8.1.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `data`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test1`
--

CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `idcustomer` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `testid` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customername` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custlastname` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthid` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namee` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `named` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testname` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testnumber` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testnamee` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
--  data for table `test1`
--

INSERT INTO 'test1' (`idcustomer`, `testid`, `customername`, `custlastname`, `birthid`, `name`, `namee`, `named`, `phonenumber`, `testname`, `testnumber`, `testnamee`) VALUES
(1, '45645', 'jack', 'xxx', '151', 'nameeeee', 'testtt', 'xname', '585', 'xdname', '985', 'xs'),
(2, '44524', 'adam', 'testt', '525', 'nameee', 'testttt', 'yname', '568', 'xdname', '854', 'xb'),`
```

how can i import this file into postgresql? I'm crazy from getting such error.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Well, PostgreSQL does not support the non-standard syntax used by MySQL. You need to manually fix that script to comply with the MySQL syntax

Comment: what should i fix?

Comment: For starters: det rid of the non-standard backticks. Remove the SET statements and the "engine" part in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: oh I think I got it, can you please repost the code by correcting where I'm going to change it? sorry i just started :(

Comment: Could you please edit my code for me and reply? please.. pls... @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please at least _attempt_ to solve your own question. “How to create a table and insert a few rows” is effectively what you are asking, there are plenty of resources for how to do that

Comment: @AD7six i know but I can't understand, damn it, I can't. It's been 12 hours, my head is not working well anymore, please someone fix and share this code. I feel sad and tired.. I broke up with my girlfriend. I'm depressed sorry if I offended you but could you please fix and share this code?

Comment: Sorry to hear your situation but it’s not an excuse :). There is no attempt to do what you need to do in the question - if you’ve been trying for 12 hours, what have you tried? I suggest to [look at the examples in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html), a file generated by MySQL is simply full of parse errors to Postgres, they are easy enough to fix - but you need to understand the differences first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules to convert such a script:

- remove the `SET` commands at the beginning
- remove all `` ` ``
- remove `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;`
- remove the "display hint" for integer columns (`int(x)` --> `int`)
- don't use single quotes for table names `'test1'` -> `test1`
- read the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html)

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  idcustomer int NOT NULL,
  testid varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  customername varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  custlastname varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  birthid varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  namee varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  named varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  phonenumber varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  testname varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  testnumber varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  testnamee varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test1 (idcustomer, testid, customername, custlastname, birthid, name, namee, named, phonenumber, testname, testnumber, testnamee) VALUES
(1, '45645', 'jack', 'xxx', '151', 'nameeeee', 'testtt', 'xname', '585', 'xdname', '985', 'xs'),
(2, '44524', 'adam', 'testt', '525', 'nameee', 'testttt', 'yname', '568', 'xdname', '854', 'xb'); --<< replace , with ;
```

Comment: omg damnnn thank u so much bro i love u thank youuu